# Do I need to create a two-dimensional array to add reference data with an id column into Entity Framework?

Tags: c#

I have the following code that I am using to create ContentType data:

```
        var contentTypeNames = new[] 
        { 
            "Menu",          // = 0,
            "Article",       // = 1,
            "FavoritesList", // = 2,
            "Topic",         // = 6,
            "List",          // = 7,
            "Dummy",         // = 99
        };

        foreach (string contentTypeName in contentTypeNames)
        {
            _uow.ContentTypes.Add(
                new ContentType
                {
                    id = ??,
                    Name = contentTypeName
                });
        }
```

I need to somehow add the values after the comments in as id columns. Is there a simple way that I can do this? I was thinking to create a two dimensional array but maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: How about using a list of type ContentType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<ContentType> contentTypes = new List<ContentType>();

//Fill Your List With Names and IDs
//Eg: contentTypes.Add(new ContentType(0,"Menu")) and so on and so forth then:

foreach (ContentType contentType in contentTypes )
{
        _uow.ContentTypes.Add(contentType);
}
```